# From SQL Server to NuoDB: Common Table Expressions, Stored Procedures and Bulk Uploads

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, cte

I am currently evaluating NuoDB as a replacement for SQL Server. The application is written in C#, .NET 4.0.

Now I am using features of SQL Server like:

- Common Table Expressions (I have a table with a reference to itself composing a n-level parent-chilren hierarchy)
- Stored Procedures
- Bulk Uploads

I didn't find enough reference on NuoDB to understand if it is suitable to do these things:

- Large select operations with hierarchy logics (now I use a recursive CTE on the 'items' table to accomplish this)
- Complex updates/inserts thru some kind of algorithm (stored procs would be ok)
- Bulk insert/update of 100.000+ elements (I am using bulk upload feature of SQL Server  .NET client and it works ok)

Besides this, I am also interested in partitioning, anybody has some experience in partitioning with NuoDB?

Thanks

Comment: thanks @mrdenny I don't have enough reputation to create a new tag

Comment: No problem. :) Happy to help.

Comment: You can download NuoDB for free and try for yourself. Or simply read the manual: http://www.nuodb.com/community/documentation.php

Comment: I have an instance of NuoDB already running in my box, I already searched in the manual but didn't find references to stored procedures. The reason why I put a question here, is that I would like some kind of "user-experience" from someone already skilled with NuoDB

Comment: Maybe if you told us *why* you want to switch, there might be other alternatives as well.

Comment: I really like the distributed architecture of NuoDB, in this moment I would like to be able to scale my db by simply adding "nodes"... but I don't know if it's possible with MSSQL

Comment: You can scale a MSSQL database across multiple boxes.  It isn't easy to do, but it can be done.  For 99% of databases it isn't needed, you just scale up to a bigger server.

Comment: Understood. Now I'm ok with a quad xeon and 32GB of RAM but I wanted to explore new possibilities :-) thank you guys

Comment: You might also want to have a look at Postgres-XC: http://postgres-xc.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The manual](http://www.nuodb.com/nuodb-online-documentation/references/r_SQLPages/r_CREATEPROCEDURE.html) for `CREATE PROCEDURE` states: "*Not Yet Implemented*"

[The documentation](http://www.nuodb.com/nuodb-online-documentation/references/r_SQLPages/r_SELECT.html) of the `SELECT` statement neither shows a `WITH` nor an alternative like `connect by` (as e.g. Cubrid does).

For bulkloading there is [nuoloader](http://www.nuodb.com/nuodb-online-documentation/references/r_ComPages/r_nuoloader_comref.html) but there doesn't seem to be an API for it.

But you will probably get a better answer if you post directly to the NuoDB forum: http://www.nuodb.com/community/forum.php?

I had a look at NuoDB as well and was pretty disappointed by the lack of SQL features. I guess that's not their main focus right now.

Comment: thanks, I also found this: http://www.nuodb.com/community/showthread.php?147-SQL-2003-window-functions  - I think NuoDB is not my right choice for the moment!! than you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your feedback.  NuoDB provides standards compliant SQL support, which includes strong language integration with LINQ and the Entity Framework.  Besides .NET language support, NuoDB also supports JDBC, ODBC, Node.JS, Ruby/JRuby ActiveRecord & RAILS, PHP/PDO, and Hibernate.

Most importantly we do that with elastic scale-out support, an active/active redundancy model that includes geo-redundancy, and the ability to co-locate an in memory transaction engine close to the application to avoid network overhead and latency.  Because of that we have excellent performance characteristics without the need for stored procedures or specialized bulk-loaders.

That all said, we are rapidly adding additional SQL features with each quarterly feature release and plan to release stored procedures in just a few months.  In reference to CTEs, we don't have those but we support sub-queries and views, so in many cases you can get what you need with things that the product has today.

Adam (I'm responsible for the engineering team at NuoDB)